# Change background-image of a div everytime page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

According to what I've seen in internet I should be able to change a background-image of a div everytime the page refresh with this javascript script. It's not working for some reason. Any help will be appreciated.

This the html

```
<div class="home-intro show-for-medium-up" id="home-intro">
</div>
```

This is the css

```
.home-intro{
  background-image: url("../images/1.png");
  background-color:grey;
  height:500px;
  color:$white;
  text-align:center;
  }
```

This is the js

```
<script>


function randomImage(){
  var images = [
   '../images/1.png',
   '../images/2.png',
   '../images/3.png'];
  var size = images.length;
  var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random());
  console.log(x);
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName('home-intro');
  console.log(element);
  element[0].style["background-image"] = "url("+ images[x] + ") no-repeat;";
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", randomImage);
```

Comment: Probably missing quotation marks inside generated url string

Comment: According to the example you gave, there is `1/3` probability that the image don't change, as you are relying on random(). You can better have a cookie like `document.cookie="lastimg=1";` if you have just shown 1st image.
Now on page load, omit that option, and use random().

Comment: Adding the background-repeat property (ie. no-repeat) is not valid for background-image. Try `"url("+ images[x] + ");"` or alternatively use `style["background"]`.

Comment: In your css file, `color:$white;` probably isn't helping

Answer (score 4):

The only issue is that you are trying to set the no-repeat attribute of the `background-image` property.  *no-repeat* is an attribute of the `background` property.

http://codepen.io/kevinfargason/pen/EjEeMa

Comment: You were totally right. I've changed background-image to background and now is working just fine. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would just do

```
<body onload="randomImage()">`
```

and use

```
var x=Math.floor(size * Math.random());
```

in

```
document.getElementById("home-intro").style.backgroundImage = "../images/" + x + ".png";
```

EDIT:

Or jQuery

```
$(function(){
    var x=Math.floor(size * Math.random());
    $('#home-intro').css('backgroundImage', '../images/' + x + '.png');
});
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work for me. I'm using angular as well <body ng-app="app"> so I'm not sure if the body onload would fit ok. What it has worked pretty well is to change the background-image to background as the previous answer said.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the height to the style.

```
function randomImage(){
   var images = ["./hanuman.png","./jesus.jpg","./hanuman.png"];
   var size = images.length;
   var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random());
   console.log(x);
   document.getElementById("homeintro").style.height="1000px";
  document.getElementById("homeintro").style.backgroundImage = 
  "url("+images[x] +")";
                }
```